# PHP operator Procedence

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

Can anybody figure out how the following statement evaluates to 7?

echo (int)( (0.1+0.7)*10 );

I was trying the operator precedence in PHP. So, if there is anybody who can help, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 0.1 != 0.1 as we know it.. [tony the pony](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the `(int)` part, and run the follwing code instead:

```
echo number_format(((0.1+0.7)*10), 20);
```

The output will be `7.99999999999999911182`. This value parsed to an integer will result to 7, as parsing a value to an integer will always floor the value.
Reading the [following article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) should give you an idea of what's going on here.

In short, double values are always a binary value, and through that a 'product of 2^n', whichever will be the nearest to the decimal you said it should be. And with 2^n you dont have any chance to reach **exactly** 0.1.

Comment: Pony story puts a smile on my face and is complete true.   And some extra proof   printf("%b", (0.1+0.7)*10); // 111 binary  7 decimal